# Testing an outbound HTTP call with sockets?

Tags: python, django, sockets, asyncsocket, webhooks

I'm trying to write a unit test for a webhooks callback in django. My application is set up so that, when I run a bit of code, it sends a POST request to the URL of my choice -- this is the functionality I'm trying to test.

I'd like to set up a socket that listens for this request and tells me if it was sent or not. I imagine this goes something like this:

```
import socket

def webHooksTest(self):
    targetURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind('localhost', 8000)
    s.listen(1)
    s.accept()

    # Code that triggers POST request goes here

    self.assertNotEqual(s.recvd(), None, "WebHooks URL did not receive anything")
```

As is, this won't work at all, because the program will get hung up on the s.accept() line and never send the request.

I'm completely new to asynchronous programming and could use some advice. From examining the Python docs, I'm fairly sure that the socket module alone can't do this -- I need some asynchronous magic.

Answer (score 1):

The socket library cannot do this alone. Take a look at [python twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac).
This should help you. Though I haven't tried it out with django yet.